# How do I call WCF service.Abort() when service was creating using spring.net wcf:channelfactory

Tags: c#, wcf, spring.net

I want to catch an exception and then call Abort method on the WCF channel factories which are running but I am not sure how to do that?

e.g.

```
 <wcf:channelFactory id="ShoppingService"
    channelType="solution.TShoppingService, solution"
    endpointConfigurationName="ServiceEndPoint" />
```

**The service is in abort state.**

I get the reference of the service as

```
IApplicationContext context = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
context["TShoppingService]...
```

but how do I call the abort method?

Comment: Not familiar with spring.net, but couldn't you cast the service reference to `ICommunicationObject` and call `Abort()`?

Answer (score 1):

Tim's solution works:

```
((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)context["ShoppingService"]).Abort();
```

Comment: If I do that in global.asax application error event then if a user navigates back, how would I re instanciate the channel factory?